# Finding the number of permutations of $\{1,\cdots,6\}$ which do not contain 3 consecutive integers.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I tried to find the number of permutations of $\{1,\cdots,6\}$ which do not contain

the strings 123, 234, 345, or 456 using the following method,

and I would like to find out why this method does not give the right answer.

(In particular, which permutations does it count incorrectly?)

---

Take the total number of permutations and then subtract those with 3 consecutive integers, add back those with 4 consecutive integers, subtract the ones with 5 consecutive integers, and finally add the one permutation with all digits consecutive to get

$6!-4\cdot4!+3\cdot3!-2\cdot2!+1\cdot1!=720-96+18-4+1=\color{blue}{639}$.

Comment: I think you also need to apply GPIE within the sets of permutations with 5 consecutive integers (and other similar cases), otherwise you will "double count" some of these, e.g. there are three permutations with at least 5 consecutive digits: $612345, 234561,12356$. The last one can easily be overcounted.

Comment: The number of permutations that include two patterns is not always $3!$. For instance, there are only $2!$ permutations that include both 123 and 345.

Comment: @ByronSchmuland I agree with your observation.  (I used a different approach, though, which doesn't give the right answer.)

Comment: @Marconius You're right - I am double-counting 123456 when I am counting the number of permutations with 5 consecutive integers, but I am subtracting it once in the next term.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears very difficult to answer this question using GPIE. So, count the number of permutations for distinct cases instead, and use symmetry where possible.

Let $R_n$ be the set of all permutations having a maximal run of $n$ consecutive digits in order but not having another disjoint run of three or more (there is one permutation having two disjoint runs of three consecutive digits), and $R_{3,3}$ be the set of all permutations having two disjoint runs of three.

Let $N(\ldots,x,y,z,\ldots)$ be the number of permutations having $(x,y,z)$ in order starting at any digit in the permutation, and $N(\ast,x,y,z,\tilde{}m,\ldots)$ be the number of permutations having $(x,y,z)$ (starting in the second digit) followed by **anything other than** $m$, and an otherwise unrestricted first digit.

Then $$\begin{align}
N(R_3) &= N(\ldots,1,2,3,\ldots) + N(\ldots,2,3,4,\ldots) + N(\ldots,3,4,5,\ldots) + N(\ldots,4,5,6,\ldots) \\
&= 2N(\ldots,1,2,3,\ldots) + 2N(\ldots,2,3,4,\ldots)\qquad(\text{by symmetry})
\end{align}$$

and 
$$\begin{align}
N(\ldots,1,2,3,\ldots) &= N(1,2,3,\tilde{}4,\ast,\ast) + N(\ast,1,2,3,\tilde{}4,\ast) + N(\ast,\ast,1,2,3,\tilde{}4) + (N(\ast,\ast,\ast,1,2,3) - N(4,5,6,1,2,3)) \\
&= 4 + 4 + 4 + (6-1) \\
&= 17 
\end{align}$$

and 
$$\begin{align}
N(\ldots,2,3,4,\ldots) &= N(2,3,4,\tilde{}5,\ast,\ast) + N(\tilde{}1,2,3,4,\tilde{}5,\ast) + N(\ast,\tilde{}1,2,3,4,\tilde{}5) + N(\ast,\ast,\tilde{}1,2,3,4) \\
&= 4 + 3 + 3 + 4 \\
&= 14 
\end{align}$$

So $\boxed{N(R_3) = 2(17) + 2(14) = 62}$

Then $$\boxed{N(R_{3,3}) = N(4,5,6,1,2,3) = 1}$$

Also $$\begin{align}
N(R_4) &= N(\ldots,1,2,3,4,\ldots) + N(\ldots,2,3,4,5,\ldots) + N(\ldots,3,4,5,6,\ldots) \\
&= 2N(\ldots,1,2,3,4,\ldots) + N(\ldots,2,3,4,5,\ldots)\qquad(\text{by symmetry})
\end{align}$$

where 
$$\begin{align}
N(\ldots,1,2,3,4,\ldots) &= N(1,2,3,4,\tilde{}5,\ast) + N(\ast,1,2,3,4,\tilde{}5) + N(\ast,\ast,1,2,3,4) \\
&= 1 + 1 + 2 \\
&= 4 
\end{align}$$

and 
$$\begin{align}
N(\ldots,2,3,4,5,\ldots) &= N(2,3,4,5,\tilde{}6,\ast) + N(\tilde{}1,2,3,4,5,\tilde{}6) + N(\ast,\tilde{}1,2,3,4,5) \\
&= 1 + 1 + 1 \\
&= 3 
\end{align}$$

So $\boxed{N(R_4) = 2(4) + 3 = 11}$

Also $$\begin{align}
N(R_5) &= N(\ldots,1,2,3,4,5,\ldots) + N(\ldots,2,3,4,5,6,\ldots) \\
&= 2N(\ldots,1,2,3,4,5,\ldots)\qquad(\text{by symmetry})
\end{align}$$

where 
$$\begin{align}
N(\ldots,1,2,3,4,5,\ldots) &= N(1,2,3,4,5,\tilde{}6) + N(\ast,1,2,3,4,5) \\
&= 0 + 1 \\
&= 1 
\end{align}$$

So $\boxed{N(R_5) = 2(1) = 2}$

Finally $\boxed{N(R_6) = 1}$

So the number of permutations without three digits in order is given by:
$$\begin{align}
6! - N(R_3) - N(R_{3,3}) - N(R_4) - N(R_5) - N(R_6) 
&= 720 - 62 - 1 - 11 - 2 - 1 \\
&= 643
\end{align}$$

Comment: There is a potentially simpler way. Every run of six gets counted as two different runs of five, so $N(R_5) = 2\cdot 2! - 2\cdot 1 = 2$. Every run of six gets counted as three different runs of four, and every maximal run of five gets counted as two different runs of four, so $N(R_4) = 3\cdot 3! - 3N(R_6) - 2N(R_5) = 18-3-2\cdot2 = 11$. Runs of three might be trickier.

Answer (score 0):

Let $A_i$ be the set of permutations containing the string $i, i+1, i+2$ for $1\le i\le 4$, and

let $S$ be the set of all permutations of $\{1,\cdots,6\}$.

Then $\displaystyle\big|A_1^c\cap\cdots\cap A_4^c\big|=\big|S\big|-\sum_{i}\big|A_i\big|+\sum_{i<j}\big|A_i\cap A_j\big|-\sum_{i<j<k}\big|A_i\cap A_j\cap A_k\big|+\big|A_1\cap\cdots\cap A_4\big|$

$\displaystyle\hspace{1.4 in}=6!-4\cdot4!+\big(3\cdot3!+3\cdot2!\big)-\big(2\cdot2!+2\cdot1\big)+1=643.$

---

Your method counts each of the following permutations twice, instead of just once,

when the number of permutations in the complement is being counted:

$\hspace{.5 in}123456, \;\;612345,\;\;234561,\;\;456123$